# dynamically adjusting div height to keep footer at bottom if content doesn't fill window

Tags: javascript, html, css, resize

I need to adjust the container div height so that it keeps the footer at the bottom of the window  onload and onresize when the content is too short but not if content pushes the footer off. I've tried variations of the css min-height:100% but it doesn't work. I've managed to make it work onload with this:

```
<div class="header></div>
<script>
 var h = window.innerHeight-205;
 document.write('<div id="container" class="container" style="min-height: ' + h + 'px;">');
</script>
  ....content of container....
</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

but when the window is resized my footer ends up in the middle of the page or off the page. I've tried calling a resize function but never seem to get it to reset the height. The codes I tried were:

```
function resetHeight () {
var h = window.innerHeight-205;
document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("height",h);
}
```

and

```
function resetHeight () {
var h = window.innerHeight-205;
document.getElementById("container").height = h;
}
```

I'm trying to use only javascript and css, not jquery. I'm not too familiar with JS so if I'm missing something to make the function call work please let me know! I'm not concerned about older browsers, just IE9+ and such, it also needs to work on iPads when the user rotates their screen...

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a css aproach, like the one outlined here:  http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Comment: I tried it... it does put the footer at the bottom but now my content area doesn't go to the bottom which is a problem since my bg has a color and the content area is white...

Comment: I should also mention, in order to make a box-shadow effect on my header work properly i've declared body position: relative and container position: absolute. Not sure if that makes a difference for the stickyfooter solution...